# Importing bs4 in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, python-3.5

I have installed both Python 3.5 and Beautifulsoup4. When I try to import bs4, I get the error below. Is there any fix for that? Or should I just install Python 3.4 instead? 
Please be very explicit - I am new to programming. Many thanks!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python 3.5\lib\sit-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 30, in    <module>
   from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectionMarkup
  File "C:\Python 3.5\lib\sit-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 308, in <module>
   from . import _htmlparser
  File "C:\Python 3.5\lib\sit-packages\bs4\_htmlparser.py", line 7, in <module>
   from html.parser import ( 
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLParseError'
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Update:** Starting with 4.4.0, `BeautifulSoup` is compatible with Python 3.5. Upgrade:

```
pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4
```

---

**Old answer:**

Because of the changes made for [Deprecate strict mode of HTMLParser](http://bugs.python.org/issue15114) issue:

> Issue #15114: the strict mode and argument of HTMLParser,
>   HTMLParser.error, and the HTMLParserError exception have been removed.

I'm afraid `beautifulSoup4` is not compatible with Python 3.5 at the moment. Use Python 3.4.

Answer (score 19):

Update: BeautifulSoup 4.4.0 has been updated to be python3.5 compatible, so a `pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4` should do the trick if you are still hitting this issue.

Comment: probably going to be pip version specific, try `pip3.5 install --upgrade beautifulsoup4` or it will upgrade bs4 for your default python version (2.7 on most *nix)

Comment: sudo pip3 install --upgrade beautifulsoup4

Answer (score 4):

I've sent the author a followup about this bug. If you want to install BeautifulSoup on Python 3.5a, I've uploaded a working patch of the source code to github.

https://github.com/jjangsangy/BeautifulSoup4

You can install it using `setup.py` or just copy & paste this code into terminal.

```
git clone https://github.com/jjangsangy/BeautifulSoup4 \
    && cd BeautifulSoup4 \
    && python3.5 setup.py install
```

I'm assuming here that since you're trying out 3.5a your python interpreter is installed with proper user permissions for your `site-packages` directory so no sudo invocation is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. I changed for python 3.3 and everything is working well.

Comment: @AndyTerra A bit late to the party here, but this link worked for me: https://github.com/wention/BeautifulSoup4.git