# 'HTMLParseError' when importing 'wikipedia' module in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, wikipedia

I installed the 'wikipedia' module on my Windows 7 machine with `pip install wikipedia`, but when I run this simple script:

```
import wikipedia
print (wikipedia.summary("Wikipedia"))
```

I get an error that says `ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLParseError'`. I'm using Python version 3.5 and the latest version of the wikipedia module. Is there another library that will give me this function?

Comment: which python version you are using 3.5?

Comment: @VaibhavMule the full output from `print (sys.version)` is `3.5.0a4 (v3.5.0a4:413e0e0004f4, Apr 19 2015, 17:42:14) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]`

Comment: This is wrong syntax print (wikipedia.summary("Wikipedia") it should print (wikipedia.summary("Wikipedia"))

Comment: @VaibhavMule sorry, that's what I have in my script. I just missed the last parenthesis when I copied it over. Edited the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29059038/3259815)

It's a bug in newer version of beutifulsoup, try doing this.

```
git clone https://github.com/jjangsangy/BeautifulSoup4 \
    && cd BeautifulSoup4 \
    && python3.5 setup.py install
```