# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4' even after installing and re-installing

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to run my Python file. (py name.py)

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 294, in <module>
    from . import _htmlparser
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_htmlparser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from html.parser import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLParseError' from 'html.parser' (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\html\parser.py)
```

I installed this library using "pip".
After the library is completely removed and installed again, this error appears when you run this code.

```
  File "name.py", line 9, in <module>
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Comment: Try `pip install -U beautifulsoup4`

Comment: Which python version you are using?

Comment: @user3401493 i use 3.7.3

Comment: @Thepersonwiththequestion: Relevant [htmlparseerror-in-python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215242/htmlparseerror-when-importing-wikipedia-module-in-python3)

Comment: @stovfl The repository specified there does not exist.

Comment: @sentence I tried, but the error remains.

Comment: @Thepersonwiththequestion: It's 3 Years ago, do `pip3 show beautifulsoup4` to find your used version. According to the linked Question it's dependant to the version.

Comment: @stovfl Yes, this error occurs depending on the Python version, but even after reinstalling the library an error appears(edited the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. First I deleted all BS4 mentions from my PC. Then in CMD moved on path:

`C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts`.

And spent there the command:

`pip install beautifulsoup4`