# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup Error

Tags: python-3.x

I have this error when importing Beautiful Soup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  File "C:\Users\pood1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from .builder import builder_registry, ParserRejectedMarkup
  File "C:\Users\pood1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 308, in <module>
    from . import _htmlparser
  File "C:\Users\pood1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-    packages\bs4\builder\_htmlparser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from html.parser import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLParseError'
Python:3.6.1 , BeautifulSoup:4-4.3.2
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing bs4 in Python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745153/importing-bs4-in-python-3-5)

Comment: I solved this problem. Thank you. The problem was my python version. After I change the version to 3.5.3, This error was go away!!

Comment: If you solved the problem, please add the solution as an answer and mark it accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you upgrade to the latest version of Beautiful Soup?

```
pip3 install --upgrade beautifulsoup4
```

This error should be fixed in the latest version. BeautifulSoup 4.4.0 has been updated to be python3.5 compatible

Comment: Thank you. I sovle this problem. Thank you very much!!

Comment: If my answer answered your question can you please accept it and up vote?